# MVC3 VB: Sort by date and time

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have table with date/time column and person column. Each person has multiple records for each day. What I need to do is next: I need to get first record for each person for each day... Can this be done in MVC3 Visual Basic and Entity framework?
Thanks in advance

Comment: re your edit: Yes, you can nest GroupBy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Surely you can do it using LINQ Query.

Hope following query is useful to you.

```
PersonRecords.GroupBy(pr => pr.Person)
.Select(pr=>pr.OrderBy(pr1 => pr1.DateTimeField).FirstOrDefault());
```

Hope this help!

Answer (score 1):

```
var results = db.Schedules
    .GroupBy(s => s.Person) //grouping for each person
    .Select(s => s.Where(s.DateProp >= DateTime.Today)
        .OrderByDescending(s => s.DateProp).FirstOrDefault()); //first event today
```